# How to set default option for <select> based on PHP variable (POST / GET / SESSION etc.)

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using HTML + PHP to build a web App.

I wanted to create an editable form that includes a couple of `<select>` fields. As an example, we can assume that I want to create a user profile.

The thing is, when new user wants to edit some data about himself, all fields are empty. For the field `sex` it may look like this:

```
<select class="form-select" name="sex" required>
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

or:

```
<select class="form-select" name="sex" required>
    <option selected value="">-</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

Whereby default the empty value described by "-" will be displayed.

But what about when the user already has filled that field? Let's assume we have an object variable `$user` and may access his/hers sex by `$user->sex`. By default, I want the `<select>` to be selected with the proper attribute. Using PHP I may go for something like this:

```
<select class="form-select" name="sex" required>
    <?php if ($user->sex == 'M') : ?>
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option selected value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    <?php elseif($user->sex == 'F' : ?>
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option selected value="F">Female</option>
    <?php else : ?>
        <option selected value="">-</option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

But that requires a lot of `if`, `elseif` statements. As an example, I've provided only three-optional field. What about when there are more options?

Is there any elegant solution to choose a selected option of `<select>`, based on a variable (object fetched from database / POST / GET / SESSION - does not really matter), without using so many `ifs`? At best, I'd like to list possible options only once and then tell the site which is to be chosen by default.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: actually you can use javascript, it`s more easier

Answer (score 1):

Why do you repeat the options? Just check every option if it needs to be selected...

```
<select class="form-select" name="sex" required>
    <option <?php if($user->sex == "") echo "selected" ?> value="">-</option>
    <option <?php if($user->sex == "M") echo "selected" ?> value="M">Male</option>
    <option <?php if($user->sex == "F") echo "selected" ?> value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Kazakh JavaScript is not necessary for this. The user's choice is available on the server side, so php should deliver the dynamic page right away.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP (the first project in fact), so I don't come up right away with the best solution patterns. This one looks much better than what I've proposed. Thanks!